Is there a way to disable default indices in ELK?
I'm using basic ELK setup + I have a couple of elastic agents. Agents (and ELK components for that matter) create system indices that I don't really use. I'd like to disable the creation of those indices and/or delete them. Is it safe to delete them? Also is there a mechanism to prevent such indices from being created at all?
I've tried nothing at this point. Since I'd like to know what is safe and possible to do. I expect to disable and/or delete unused system indices.

It's never safe to delete system indices.
It's not recommended to do any manuel operation to system indices.

I am sharing some API calls below to update the cluster settings and to prevent some automatically created system indices.
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": { 
    "ingest.geoip.downloader.enabled" : "false"
  }
}

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.5/geoip-processor.html#geoip-cluster-settings
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled": false
  }
}

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/monitoring-settings.html#monitoring-collection-settings
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": { 
    "cluster.deprecation_indexing.enabled": "true"
  }
}

or
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "logger.org.elasticsearch.deprecation": "OFF"
  }
}

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/logging.html#deprecation-logging
If you need to get rid of other indices too, find the correct API call, if any, and disable them.
